# How to install SharePoint 2013 Installation with SQL Server Authentication

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, authentication, sql-server

I'm just curious about the steps required to install Sharepoint 2013 using SQL Server Authentication.  Also if there are any drawbacks that i might not be aware of.

Here are some steps i currently think are required for installing using SQL Authentication and i would just like them confirmed and added too if i'm missing something.

1. Ensure "mixed-mode" auth is active on the SQL Server
2. Create a SQL login in the SQL Server with following roles: DBCreator & SecurityAdmin
3. Run the "New-SPConfigurationDatabase" SharePoint PowerShell command on the web server using the -DatabaseCredentials flag to pass the SQL Login details

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx) provides a few good points about drawbacks.

> - **If a user is a Windows domain user who has a login and password for
>
>     Windows, he must still provide another (SQL Server) login and
>
>     password to connect. Keeping track of multiple names and passwords is 
>     difficult for many users. Having to provide SQL Server credentials
>
>     every time that one connects to the database can be annoying.**
> - SQL Server Authentication cannot use Kerberos security protocol.
> - Windows offers additional password policies that are not available for SQL
>     Server logins.
> - The encrypted SQL Server Authentication login
>     password, must be passed over the network at the time of the
>     connection. Some applications that connect automatically will store
>     the password at the client. These are additional attack points.

From personal experience.

Pros:

- Greater control as far as customizing experience and password recovery
- You can have external users who would not be able to use other Auth methods
- It is easier to make test users (Than using AD)

Cons:

- You will need to create a customized log in system in some way. Asp.net/MVC log in controls work, but sometimes need a little help.
- You will need a customized administration system if you do not want all admins to have database/server access.
- Web.config modifications can be tricky

Comment: Thanks thantos... do you actually have a step-by-step guide as to how i would install using SQL Authentication by chance?  I just want to make sure i do it correctly.

Comment: @Adamh409 - I'm trying to setup SP 2016 using SQL authentication (SQL 2014), wondering if you can share any guideline or PS scripts to configure that? Appreciate any feedback!